# Proper way to use Material UI in reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, styles, material-ui

I've recently started using Material UI and I'm not sure what is the proper way to use it. There are some times when I want to customize the styles of the Material UIcomponents. But for that I have to work in the ".js" file, which I think isn't appropriate.

Is there a way where one can store multiple custom styles/components of Material UI components in a different file and then import the styles/components from there?

Thanks!

Comment: CSS in JS is nothing `not appropriate`, check the MUI style document: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in separating the styles from the components.

I for one even import the `makeStyles` hook inside the `styles.js`.

```js
// styles.js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  main: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

export default styles;
```

*You can import the `useStyles` in the component if you like that better*

```js
// Component.jsx
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles';

const Component = () => {
    const classes = styles();
    return (
      <WhatEverComponent classsName={classes.main}/>
    );
}
```

> LE: `makeStyles` in Component

```js
// styles.js

const styles = theme => ({
  main: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
});

export default styles;
```

```js
// Component.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import stylesObj from './styles';

const styles = makeStyles(stylesObj);

const Component = () => {
    const classes = styles();
    return (
      <WhatEverComponent classsName={classes.main}/>
    );
}
```

I've made also a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-dust-k85ij?file=/src/App.js:195-233). You can check how both work. 
I would suggest to use the first variant.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me how should I use the makestyles in my component?

Comment: There are so many things that work differently in mui. Like if I wanna change the color of the text,how do I do it? the background and everything else. Is there a proper documentation that lists out all the properties/styles of mui?

Comment: They are the same CSS props but with camelCase not with dash, so `background-color` is `backgroundColor` and so on...

Comment: Okay,thanks a lot, but somehow makestyles isn't working for me, but making styled components in a separate file and exporting them from there, is working fine for me. Is this the best approach to override mui styles? making your own styled components?

Comment: Why doesn't your `makeStyles` work. Can you post your code? You can use style components as well but you will not be able to use the theme helpers and palette. Also I forgot to send you a link to CSS refs in JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference